# Selected value of select box is not getting removed

Tags: drop-down-menu

i have an select box where i have removed few values from select and loaded in jsp its working in all browsers but in safari browser the value is not getting removed  at first time of my click but while clicking next the value gets removed  can any one suggest me with an answer Thanks in advance

Comment: Some code would be nice ...

Comment: If some browser do and some don't... Check your functions and check their compatibility.

Comment: Please edit your original post and use markup (4 spaces on each line before the code to use code block)

Comment: function blockTempPolicy() {
  //blocks Foreign and Temp Policy
   $("#prefix1RC option[value='11']").remove();
   $("#prefix1RC option[value='12']").remove();
  }                                                                                                         on focus

Comment: function blockTempPolicy1(){
 //blocks Foreign and Temp Policy
  $("#prefix1RC option[value='11']").attr('disabled','disabled');
  $("#prefix1RC option[value='12']").attr('disabled','disabled');
} on keypress